# Deploy to EKS cluster using AWS codepipleine

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, aws-codepipeline, amazon-eks

I'm trying to automate deployment on EKS cluster using AWS codepipeline and was referring to the page: [AWS CodePipeline and deployingto EKS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52322707/aws-codepipeline-and-deployingto-eks)

I am following the same steps as mentioned in the buildspec.yaml file but I am getting following error:

```
[Container] 2020/01/05 08:26:35 Running command kubectl apply -f $CODEBUILD_SRC_DIR/Takenaka.Api.User/Takenaka.Api.User/hello-k8s.yml 
Error from server (Forbidden): error when retrieving current configuration of: 
Resource: "apps/v1, Resource=deployments", GroupVersionKind: "apps/v1, Kind=Deployment" 
Name: "takenaka-user", Namespace: "default" 
Object: &{map["apiVersion":"apps/v1" "kind":"Deployment" "metadata":map["annotations":map["kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration":""] "name":"takenaka-user" "namespace":"default"] "spec":map["replicas":'\x01' "selector":map["matchLabels":map["app":"takenaka-user"]] "template":map["metadata":map["labels":map["app":"takenaka-user"]] "spec":map["containers":[map["image":"591209811908.dkr.ecr.ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com/takenaka-ecr-repo:takenaka.user-4" "name":"takenaka-user" "ports":[map["containerPort":'P']]]]]]]]} 
from server for: "/codebuild/output/src658704233/src/git-codecommit.ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com/v1/repos/Takenaka/Takenaka.Api.User/Takenaka.Api.User/hello-k8s.yml": deployments.apps "takenaka-user" is forbidden: User "Kubernetesdeployment" cannot get resource "deployments" in API group "apps" in the namespace "default"
```

Comment: Seems like an issue with role mapping in aws auth configmap. Please provide output of $ kubectl describe cm aws-auth. Also check the authenticator control plane logs (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/control-plane-logs.html).

Answer (score 0):

> User "Kubernetesdeployment" cannot get resource "deployments" in API group "apps" in the namespace "default"

If "Kubernetesdeployment" is a ServiceAccount that AWS CodePipeline uses to deploy, it looks like it is missing the necessary RBAC permissions to deploy "Deployment" in namespace "default".

[Using RBAC Authorization](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/rbac/) may be helpful. Usually, you want to create and read both "Deployment", "Service" and possibly "Ingress" for deploying apps to a specific namespace.

From the link that you had followed, it looks like it miss point 4.

> 4. Make kubernetes_deployment role as authorized in eks cluster

alternatively, that you have set the permissions to a different service account name? `username: kubernetes_deployment` is named `Kubernetesdeployment` in your error message.

Comment: Hi Jonas, we have made the permissions accordingly as mentioned in the page I'm referring to. We are able to deploy manually but not using this buildspec.yml.

Comment: Jonas - can you also tell me how to enable path based routing for my microservices using ALB ingress .

Answer (score 0):

Please also look at AWS recommended deployment methodology to EKS with CodePipeline:

Continuous Deployment to Kubernetes using AWS CodePipeline, AWS CodeCommit, AWS CodeBuild, Amazon ECR and AWS Lambda - https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/devops/continuous-deployment-to-kubernetes-using-aws-codepipeline-aws-codecommit-aws-codebuild-amazon-ecr-and-aws-lambda/